# google charts loader google.charts.load not triggering callback

Tags: javascript, angular, google-visualization, systemjs

I have a mysterious error which only started occurring today. I am using the google charts library in my angular2 web application and I load the appropriate package **before** initialising the app. This morning when I tried to reload the page, nothing happened!

I am using systemJS as my module loader for the project. To load the google charts package before starting the application, I have this line near the bottom of my systemjs.config.js:

```
google.charts.load('current',{ 'packages': ['corechart'] } );
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(go);

function go(){
  console.log('go!');
  System.import ( baseUrl + '/app/main.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
}
```

My problem is that, from this morning, `go` is not called!

- I have checked that the loader is being downloaded and it is. It is using version 45 and has been for a while. Nothing new here.
- I have checked just in case the function name `go` was too generic and defined elsewhere - this is not the case.
- google.charts.load is not throwing any errors at all.
- No requests are being made on the network from the loader.
- I am getting this error when running the project **locally**, and currently I'm getting no errors on the production site.

Any Ideas would be very much appreciated - thanks in advance!

---

**Update**

I have been able to load the visualization object with a bit of a bodge. I've specifically loaded version 45 of the loader:

```
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45/loader.js
```

and then in my configjs I have:

```
  google.charts.versionSpecific.load('45',{ 'packages': ['corechart'] } );
```

The setOnCallback still doesn't work, but I reckon that at the moment, the library downloads before it is needed, so I don't get any errors. This is **not** an ideal solution, or even a correct one. I would still like to find the root cause.

---

**Update 2**

As of this morning, the exact same code is working again. I can only think that there must have been some temporary change in the code in the loader that caused it to not do anything useful. I will have a look in the forums to see if there is any evidence of this.

Comment: Is the order correct? I would suggest to start with function definition "go", then add callback "setOnLoadCallback" and only then call "load"

Comment: The order is fine due to js hoisting - I have just double checked for sanity though.

Comment: you can also add the callback directly in the `load` statement -- `.load('current',{ 'callback': go, 'packages': ['corechart'] } );`

Comment: That has no effect on my problem unfortunately :(